# How to Convert list of date in x- axis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, list, datetime

I am working with databases, and my goal is to create a lightcurve, with the time on the x axis (horizontal axis).
I have a list like these :

> (20020731, 20030320, 20030613, 20030906, 20040328, 20040428, 20040705, ........)

with : year/month/day

And I want to convert it into day's interval for my curve.

Have someone an idea how can I do it ?

Comment: can you provide a [mre]? or at least some more details; what's the data type of the dates (string, int, ...), what do you mean by "day's interval" (resampling)?

Comment: You may have to consider using Python's datetime module and a datetime object's strptime() method (assuming your dates are strings). I guess that the 'interval' you refer to is the difference between the dates you have and some base date. Bear in mind that datetime objects support subtraction so it's very easy to calculate the number of days between two dates

Comment: 20020731 == 2002-07-31 ???